# Non-static method App\Console\Setting::KS() should not be called statically - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have made my own class

```
<?php

namespace App\Çonsole;

use App\KernelSetting;

class Setting
{

    /**
     * @param $setting
     * @return
     */
    function KS($setting)
    {
        return KernelSetting::where('setting', $setting)->first()->value;
    }
}
```

Now I am calling it like this `Setting::KS('review_time_limit')`

How do I return the `value` from the database entry I get?

I get this

```
Non-static method App\Console\Setting::KS() should not be called statically
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear, you need to make the method static in order to call it like that.

```
static function KS($setting)
{
    return KernelSetting::where('setting', $setting)->first()->value;
}
```

You can read more about static here : 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php